# Looking for more pythonic list comparison solution

Tags: python, list

Ok so I have two lists:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [1, 1, 2, 5, 6]
```

I compare them in such a way so I get the following output:

```
x = [3, 4]
y = [1, 5, 6]
```

The basic is idea to go through each list and compare them. If they have an element in common remove that element. But only one of that element not all of them. If they don't have an element in common leave it. Two identical lists would become x = [], y = []

Here is my rather hacked up and pretty lame solution. I hoping other can recommend a better and / or more pythonic way of doing this. 3 loops seems excessive...

```
    done = True

    while not done:
        done = False
        for x in xlist:
            for y in ylist:
                if x == y:
                    xlist.remove(x)
                    ylist.remove(y)
                    done = False
        print xlist, ylist
```

Thanks as always for taking the time to read this question. XOXO

Comment: is order of elements in lists important?

Comment: what you are doing isn't really "comparing" the lists

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible that the data structure you are looking for is the [**multiset**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) (or "bag"), and if so, a good way to implement it in Python is to use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> x = Counter([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> y = Counter([1, 1, 2, 5, 6])
>>> x - y
Counter({3: 1, 4: 1})
>>> y - x
Counter({1: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1})
```

If you want to convert the `Counter` objects back to lists with multiplicity, you can use the [`elements`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.elements) method:

```
>>> list((x - y).elements())
[3, 4]
>>> list((y - x).elements())
[1, 5, 6]
```

Comment: nice, but it looks like it's python3 only, isn't it?

Comment: `collections.Counter` was introduced in 2.7, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @tomasz - his link leads to the v2.7.2 doc.

Comment: @Nate, you're right, there is a link. It just looked like a syntax coloring... Good excuse to upgrade my default python version then!

Comment: Might be slower, but I like it. In python readability is king :)

Answer (score 3):

To build on Gareth's answer:

```
>>> a = Counter([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> b = Counter([1, 1, 2, 5, 6])
>>> (a - b).elements()
[3, 4]
>>> (b - a).elements()
[1, 5, 6]
```

Benchmark code:

```
from collections import Counter
from collections import defaultdict
import random

# short lists
#a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9]
#b = [1, 1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 8, 10]

# long lists
a = []
b = []

for i in range(0, 1000):
    q = random.choice((1, 2, 3, 4))
    if q == 1:
        a.append(i)
    elif q == 2:
        b.append(i)
    elif q == 3:
        a.append(i)
        b.append(i)
    else:
        a.append(i)
        b.append(i)
        b.append(i)

# Modifies the lists in-place! Naughty! And it doesn't actually work, to boot.
def original(xlist, ylist):
    done = False

    while not done:
        done = True
        for x in xlist:
            for y in ylist:
                if x == y:
                    xlist.remove(x)
                    ylist.remove(y)
                    done = False
    return xlist, ylist # not strictly necessary, see above


def counter(xlist, ylist):
    x = Counter(xlist)
    y = Counter(ylist)
    return ((x-y).elements(), (y-x).elements())


def nasty(xlist, ylist):
    x = sum(([i]*(xlist.count(i)-ylist.count(i)) for i in set(xlist)),[])
    y = sum(([i]*(ylist.count(i)-xlist.count(i)) for i in set(ylist)),[])

    return x, y


def gnibbler(xlist, ylist):
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for i in xlist: d[i] += 1
    for i in ylist: d[i] -= 1
    return [k for k,v in d.items() for i in range(v)], [k for k,v in d.items() for i in range(-v)]

# substitute algorithm to test in the call
for x in range(0, 100000):
    original(list(a), list(b))
```

Running the Insufficiently Rigorous Benchmarks[tm] (short lists are the original ones, long lists are randomly generated lists approximately 1000 entries long with a mix of matches and repeats, times given in multipliers of the Original algorithm):

```
    100K iterations, short lists    1K iterations, long lists
Original     1.0                           1.0
Counter      9.3                           0.06
Nasty        2.9                           1.4
Gnibbler     2.4                           0.02
```

Note 1: The creation of the Counter object seems to overshadow the actual algorithm at small list sizes.

Note 2: Original and gnibbler are the same at list lengths of approximately 35, above which gnibbler (and Counter) are faster.

Comment: did you accidentally double-paste the same piece of code rather than two pieces?

Comment: But wont this will scale terribly if the lists are larger?

Comment: I think the creation of the Counter object takes up a large proportion of the time for the case with small lists

Comment: If you're using a `Counter` as a multiset, then `.keys()` is not the right way to turn it back into a list, because you lose the multiplicity. You need `.elements()`.

Comment: Also, your "quick and dirty" benchmark isn't doing the same thing as the code with the Counters. First, you're modifying lists while iterating over them. Second, you update `a` and `b` in-place, so on the second call to `doit`, there's nothing left to do! No wonder it runs quickly.

Comment: Thanks, fixed... as I said, quick and dirty indeed. I added list() around the args to do a copy, but it still runs quickly for the short lists. The tests also assume that that lists are pre-sorted, which would affect timing the algorithms as well.

Comment: You're still modifying lists while iterating over them! Have you looked at `xlist` and `ylist` after executing `original`? (Also, "exponential" isn't right: the asymptotic behaviour is just cubic.)

Comment: Er, yes, that's rather the point of his original algorithm: it's modifying the lists in-place. If I weren't using his original algorithm then... I wouldn't be using his original algorithm. I'm not sure what your point is.

Comment: @Scott: It's modification *while iterating* that I'm complaining about: it gives the wrong results. But I suppose that if you are going for bug-for-bug compatibility with the OP's code then that's OK, though might need a comment to that effect.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't care about order, use `collections.Counter` to do it in one line:

```
>>> Counter(x)-Counter(y)
Counter({3: 1, 4: 1})

>>> Counter(y)-Counter(x)
Counter({1: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1})
```

If you care about order, you can probably iterate through your lists grabbing elements from the above dictionaries:

```
def prune(seq, toPrune):
    """Prunes elements from front of seq in O(N) time"""
    remainder = Counter(seq)-Counter(toPrune)
    R = []
    for x in reversed(seq):
        if remainder.get(x):
            remainder[x] -= 1
            R.insert(0,x)
    return R
```

Demo:

```
>>> prune(x,y)
[3, 4]
>>> prune(y,x)
[1, 1, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just using `collections.defaultdict` so will work on Python2.5+

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> y = [1, 1, 2, 5, 6]
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> for i in x:
...  d[i] += 1
... 
>>> for i in y:
...  d[i] -= 1
... 
>>> [k for k,v in d.items() for i in range(v)]
[3, 4]
>>> [k for k,v in d.items() for i in range(-v)]
[1, 5, 6]
```

I find this is better than range (or xrange) if the number repetitions get large

```
>>> from itertools import repeat
>>> [k for k,v in d.items() for i in repeat(None, v)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite nasty :P

```
a = sum(([i]*(x.count(i)-y.count(i)) for i in set(x)),[])
b = sum(([i]*(y.count(i)-x.count(i)) for i in set(y)),[])

x,y = a,b
```

Comment: when we see `.count` inside a loop we know it's already at least O(N^2)

Comment: @gnibbler NO! I know it when i see `sum(..., [])`! :D

Comment: I know you said it was nasty, that's why you don't get a downvote :)

Answer (score 0):

This is simple if you dont care about the duplicates:

```
>>> x=[1,2,3,4]
>>> y=[1,1,2,5,6]
>>> list(set(x).difference(set(y)))
[3, 4]
>>> list(set(y).difference(set(x)))
[5, 6]
```

Comment: hence "if you dont care about the duplicates" :)

Comment: Oh, that's the same as saying `x=y=[]` if you don't care about your data... :D